# Rails remote js errors don't produce message in chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It's well understood that a js RUNTIME error from a rails remote call will fail silently, as described here:

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/

> The problem usually isn’t that the JavaScript in the js.erb isn’t
>   being executed, it’s that it’s being executed and incurring an error.
>   By default, when jQuery processes a JavaScript response, it does two
>   things. It executes (or evaluates) the response, and also returns it
>   as a text.
>
> Except, if there is in error in the JS evaluation, we will not see
>   that error in our favorite JavaScript console; the automatic JS
>   evaluation fails silently, so it appears that jQuery is only
>   interpreting the response as text and nothing else.

Sure, you can see nothing happen and eventually figure out that the link/button was to a rails remote call, and then go to the network tab, copy the js response, and paste in the console.

**But why is this not solvable so that an error shows up in the console without having to figure all this out?**

This makes me think that's the value of the rails remote technique of dynamically updating an application should probably be limited to specific cases of rendering form partials, and otherwise, it's much simpler to maintain long-term to use the standard JQuery.ajax with the returned promise object.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions seems to be that if you use rails UJS, then you MUST look at the response for errors and then you need to paste the return value into the console to detect any errors.